# Port number coming in workbox actions

Tags: workbox

I am not able to do any action in workbox, As most of the action redirect me back to the workbox page with port number in the url. And we have not opened that port number for internal access, so it taking us to site not available page. I want to know how to avoid the port number in the worbox page action url.

Example: If i select refresh option in the workbox. its making post call to `sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox.aspx?sc_bw=1` and in response i am getting url with port number like  this below

```
{
  "commands": 
  [{
    "command":"SetAttribute",
    "value":"/temp/iconcache/people/16x16/user1.png",
    "id":"globalHeaderUserPortrait",
    "name":"src"
  },
  {
    "command":"SetPipeline",
    "value":"2D8C27809F764B95B6A1782D7A36DB57"
  }, 
  {
    "command":"SetLocation",
    "value":"https://sitename:44300/sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox.aspx?sc_bw=1&reload=1"
  }]
}
```

After that response it will redirect me to the `https://sitename:44300/sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox.aspx?sc_bw=1&reload=1` url with port number in the response which is not accessible outside the server.

Comment: Do you have this port number specified somewhere (like in the site definition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue that you described. Actually the problem is in the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm` class which represents the *Workbox Form*.

There are two methods:

```
    /// <summary>Refreshes the page.</summary>
    protected virtual void Refresh()
    {
      this.Refresh((Dictionary<string, string>) null);
    }

    /// <summary>Refreshes the page.</summary>
    /// <param name="urlArguments">The URL arguments.</param>
    protected void Refresh(Dictionary<string, string> urlArguments)
    {
      UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
      urlString["reload"] = "1";
      if (urlArguments != null)
      {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> urlArgument in urlArguments)
          urlString[urlArgument.Key] = urlArgument.Value;
      }
      Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(WebUtil.GetFullUrl(urlString.ToString()));
    }
```

In general, the problem is in the `Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(WebUtil.GetFullUrl(urlString.ToString()))` line. And is in `WebUtil.GetFullUrl(urlString.ToString())` method particularly. This method always returns the URL with the port extension.

Then, looking at details of `GetFullUrl` method where we can find that it calls GetServerUrl:

```
public static string GetFullUrl(string url)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) url, nameof (url));
  return WebUtil.GetFullUrl(url, WebUtil.GetServerUrl());
}
```

The `GetServerUrl` method looks like:

```
public static string GetServerUrl()
{
  return WebUtil.GetServerUrl(false);
}
```

Where the `false`, is `forcePort` parameter, which is always 'false'.

Let's skip a calls chain and have a look at the final view of `GetServerUrl` method:

```
public static string GetServerUrl(Uri url, bool forcePort)
{
  if (url == (Uri) null)
    return string.Empty;
  string scheme = url.Scheme;
  string host = url.Host;
  string str1 = url.Port.ToString();
  string str2 = string.Format("{0}://{1}", (object) scheme, (object) host);
  if (forcePort || str1 != "80")
    str2 += string.Format(":{0}", (object) str1);
  return str2;
}
```

Looking at this method we can see that even `forcePort` is `true`, the URL will still include port as it is not equal to 80.

So, it is why you always have the port in your URL.

You can create your `CustomWorkboxform` class and inherit it from the 'WorkboxForm'. Then try to override `protected new void Refresh(Dictionary<string, string> urlArguments)` method (using `new` keyword as this method is not virtual). Then you will have to update `Workbox.xml` with new CustomWorkboxForm code behind implementation (\sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml). There can be some another difficulties with overlapping other methods. But idea might work!

**UPDATED:**
Final implementation of CustomWorkboxFrom looks like above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Text;
using Sitecore.Web;
using Sitecore.Workflows;
using Sitecore.Workflows.Simple;

namespace Test
{
    public class CustomWorkboxForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm
    {
        /// <summary>Gets or sets the offset(what page we are on).</summary>
        /// <value>The size of the offset.</value>
        private OffsetCollection Offset = new OffsetCollection();


        /// <summary>Refreshes the page.</summary>
        protected override void Refresh()
        {
            this.Refresh(null);
        }

        /// <summary>Refreshes the page.</summary>
        /// <param name="urlArguments">The URL arguments.</param>
        protected new void Refresh(Dictionary<string, string> urlArguments)
        {
            UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
            urlString["reload"] = "1";
            if (urlArguments != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> urlArgument in urlArguments)
                    urlString[urlArgument.Key] = urlArgument.Value;
            }

            var url = WebUtil.GetFullUrl(urlString.ToString());
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            var clean = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Port,
                UriFormat.UriEscaped);

            Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(clean);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Workflow completion callback to refresh the counts of items in workflow states.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments for the workflow execution.</param>
        [UsedImplicitly]
        private void WorkflowCompleteStateItemCount(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
        {
            IWorkflow workflowFromPage = GetWorkflowFromPage();
            if (workflowFromPage == null)
                return;
            int itemCount = workflowFromPage.GetItemCount(args.PreviousState.StateID);
            if (PageSize > 0 && itemCount % PageSize == 0)
            {
                int num = Offset[args.PreviousState.StateID];
                if (itemCount / PageSize > 1 && num > 0)
                    Offset[args.PreviousState.StateID]--;
                else
                    Offset[args.PreviousState.StateID] = 0;
            }
            Refresh(workflowFromPage.GetStates().ToDictionary((state => state.StateID), (state => Offset[state.StateID].ToString())));
        }


        private class OffsetCollection
        {
            public int this[string key]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties[key] != null)
                        return (int)Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties[key];
                    UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
                    int result;
                    if (urlString[key] != null && int.TryParse(urlString[key], out result))
                        return result;
                    return 0;
                }
                set
                {
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties[key] = (object)value;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately, if you still want to remove the port from URL, you need to include some implementation of private method defined in base class.

Comment: When creating custom class it also expect "WorkFlowCompleteStateItemCount"

Comment: @SundarRam I will have a look tomorrow how we can go around it.

Comment: thanks @Artsem Prashkovich

Comment: @SundarRam I've updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: thanks @Artsem Prashkovich